# Is it possible to set the padding character for the printf function of gawk?

Tags: awk

By default, gawk pads the content to the specified length with space character:

```
root@u2004:~# awk 'BEGIN{printf("|%+5s|\n", "abc")}'
|  abc|
root@u2004:~#
```

Is it possible to specify a custom padding character? For example, how can I get `|__abc|`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly but using GNU awk for `gensub` and assuming you don't have any other blanks in your string to be printed (`"abc"` in this case):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print gensub(/ /,"_","g",sprintf("|%5s|","abc")) }'
|__abc|
```

or using any awk whether your string contains blanks or not:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ base=sprintf("%1000s",""); gsub(/ /,"_",base);
        str="abc"; printf "|%s%s|\n", substr(base,1,5-length(str)), str }'
|__abc|
```

or:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ printf "|%s|\n", pad("abc",5,"_") }
    function pad(str,len,chr,    base) {
       base = sprintf("%*s",len-length(str),"")
       gsub(/ /,chr,base)
       return base str
    }
'
|__abc|
```

Answer (score 3):

No, that will not work. `gawk` uses the `printf` function which does not support other padding characters according to this reference:

https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/219695-printf-padding-alternate-character